# Обработка сообщений в беседе ВК через API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Создал тестовое сообщество. В настройках API создал ключ со всеми правами. В настройках событий Callback API включил все события. В настройках сообщений разрешил добавлять бота в беседу. Добавил бота в тестовую беседу из двух человек + сам бот. Запустил бота через CLI. Боту прилетают все события, кроме любых событий в этой беседе

```
<?php

namespace Program;

use \IO\Console;
use \Swoole\Http\Server;
use \Swoole\Http\Request;
use \Swoole\Http\Response;

class Main
{
    private $server;
    
    public function __construct(array $args)
    {
        $this->server = new Server(Config::SERVER_ADDR, Config::SERVER_PORT);
        $this->server->on("start", function(Server $server) { $this->Server_Start($server);});
        $this->server->on("request", function(Request $request, Response $response) { $this->Server_Request($request, $response);});
        $this->server->start();
    }

    private function Server_Start(Server $server) : void
    {
        Logger::Log("Запуск Swoole-сервера на http://" . Config::SERVER_ADDR . ":" . Config::SERVER_PORT);
    }

    private function Server_Request(Request $request, Response $response) : void
    {
        $response->header("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        if ($request->server["request_uri"] != Config::$RequestUri)
        {
            Logger::Log("Неверный URI: " . $request->server["request_uri"]);
            Logger::Log($request->rawcontent());
            $response->end("Wrong URI");
            return;
        }

        $data = json_decode($request->rawcontent(), true);

        if ($data == null)
        {
            Logger::Log("Некорректное содержимое запроса");
            Logger::Log($request->rawcontent());
            $response->end("Bad request");
            return;
        }
        if ($data["type"] == "confirmation")
        {
            Logger::Log("VK отправил запрос на подтверждение");
            if (!isset($data["group_id"]) || $data["group_id"] != Config::$GroupId)
            {
                Logger::Log("Запрос на потверждение пришёл от другого сообщества");
                $response->end("Invalid group");
                return;
            }
            if (!isset($data["secret"]) || $data["secret"] != Config::$SecretKey)
            {
                Logger::Log("Неверный ключ подтверждения. Проверьте, что в настройках сообщества и в настройках бота один и тот же Secret Key");
                $response->end("Invalid secret key");
                return;
            }
            $response->end(Config::$ConfirmResponse);
            Logger::Log("Подтверждено");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Logger::Log($request->rawcontent());
        }
        $response->end("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы боту права на получение всех сообщений из беседы дали ? (В участниках беседы настроить соотв. уровень доступа) (p.s. я правда не все пункты там нашел описанные в доке, скорее всего придется давать админа беседы) https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs?f=1.2.%2B%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%2B%D0%B2%2B%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B  А еще там есть предупреждение что версия api должна быть не ниже 5.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказывается всё это время была у меня под носом. В настройках Callback API в управлении сообществом стояла версия 5.50. А поддержка чат-ботов в беседе есть только с 5.80 версии.